# How can I open raw image files?

Tags: android, framebuffer, rooted-device

In my application , I am  able to read framebuffer data  but I cant open the image file ,I dont know why but what I came to know by searching is it is in the raw format .
Can someone tell me how  can open this raw format of data on to a human readable image format 
My code to get raw image file is as follows

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);

OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();

os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + ss.getAbsolutePath()).getBytes("ASCII"));

os.flush();

os.close();

sh.waitFor();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: My code for getting raw image is

Comment: Your "question" is impossible to answer.  What framebuffer?  How is the buffer populated?  What code are you using to try to read the buffer?  etc.

Comment: Is your question, "how can I capture the screen"?

Comment: @Simon ,yes, you are write .but  I have  manned to take the screenshot  ,but I cant open it ?Can you tell me why and how to open it ???

Answer (score 1):

If i get your question than try this:-

```
myIageView.setImageResource(R.raw.imageName);
```